# Visual Studio 2013 Solution Explorer REFRESH

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Is there a way to refresh VS 2013 Solution Explorer?
I modify files outside of VS, usually with Dream Weaver, but when I reopen VS Solution Explorer it remains unchanged.
The MS docs say there is/was a refresh button for VS 2010 but I cannot find it in VS 2013

Comment: What kind of "changes" are you expecting? Visual Studio should auto-detect any changes and prompt for a reload. Are you, by chance, working from a file share? Can you show a screenshot of a before-after situation?

There is no refresh button in VS 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this refresh button?

[image: refresh button]

If you can't find it, maybe your solution explorer pane is too narrow and the button is hidden? Note that it's only available in "Show All Files" mode (the button outlined in blue on the picture).